# handleResetPassword in custom email action handlers

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
function handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang) {
  // Localize the UI to the selected language as determined by the lang
  // parameter.
  var accountEmail;
  // Verify the password reset code is valid.
  auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {
    var accountEmail = email;

    // TODO: Show the reset screen with the user's email and ask the user for
    // the new password.

    // Save the new password.
    auth.confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function(resp) {
      // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.

      // TODO: Display a link back to the app, or sign-in the user directly
      // if the page belongs to the same domain as the app:
      // auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(accountEmail, newPassword);

      // TODO: If a continue URL is available, display a button which on
      // click redirects the user back to the app via continueUrl with
      // additional state determined from that URL's parameters.
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Error occurred during confirmation. The code might have expired or the
      // password is too weak.
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Invalid or expired action code. Ask user to try to reset the password
    // again.
  });
}
```

Using above `handleResetPassword` function I can get the email with `auth.verifyPasswordResetCode` and how to continue to`auth.confirmPasswordReset` with new password? Do I need html form? then what will be the action of that form? I'm confusing to continue to `auth.confirmPasswordReset`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a form with an input and a button but you never need to submit the form. You ask the user to enter the new password in an input field. On button click, you get the new password and call `confirmPasswordReset` with the `actionCode` and new password while cancelling the submit action.